# How to solve TS7053 issue in replace method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem. I'm trying to get data to be encoded and further used when downloading. All functionality works correctly and gives what I expect. But I get a typescript error when declaring the format constant in the place where the return occurs ( under context )

Error :
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ worksheet: string; table:string; }'.

Below is the code. Table is an element from the dom tree that I find by id

```
  const template =
    '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-mic' +
    'rosoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta cha' +
    'rset="UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:Exce' +
    "lWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/>" +
    "</x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></" +
    "xml><![endif]--></head><body>{table}</body></html>";

  const context = {
    worksheet: "tablexls",
    table,
  };

const format = template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, (m, p) => context[p]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that TypeScript doesn't know that `p` is a valid key for `context`. Maybe *you* don't know that either, because you can't be sure that all of the placeholders in the string are in fact valid keys for `context`; it depends on where that string comes from.

If you want to assume that it is, the fully type-safe way to do that is to have a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) along these lines:

```typescript
function assertsIsKeyOf<ObjectType>(object: ObjectType, key: string): asserts key is keyof ObjectType & string {
    if (!(key in object)) {
        throw new Error(`Key ${JSON.stringify(key)} expected but not found in object.`);
    }
}
```

Then your `replace` call would be:

```typescript
const format = template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, (m, p: string) => {
    assertsIsKeyOf(context, p);
    return context[p];
});
```

But you might not want to make that assumption, in which case you might want a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) instead:

```typescript
function isKeyOf<ObjectType>(object: ObjectType, key: string): key is keyof ObjectType & string {
    return key in object;
}
```

Then the call is:

```typescript
const format = template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, (m, p: string) => {
    if (!isKeyOf(context, p)) {
        // Do something to handle the fact th ekey isn't valid, like throwing an error,
        // or returning a static value
        throw new Error(`Template has invalid key ${JSON.stringify(p)}`);
    }
    return context[p];
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBbADgGwIYJgXgFAwJgHIAeACykVRgA8rIAuEbAIgFcAnMBiYMpdBAC0iAJbAOICCABmUIaERMZM8fGWrg8FrXoQGNVp269+iQSPFEYAanyEik6XIUglszevg0tqHXVRIVgooZAYAenCAdxiAOiiAZliQDgBzcIAVACVwrIBRAGEhCioAFgAGFgA+cnh0ABMaxHgodBg+dGs7QmIOCBbWAFUMgDEhAA5qkgBCISEAbVEZGFSsRGkYAE4AXRqAvYY8n3hUAHUUgGsAIxAQC4Oj33OOC4h+FogH4677AhYzy5veAtA4AOXQzSqAG8ooD3lAAL4kcI0BjgyEkVHPV7wgDyyCgonAn0xDAAIqIIGh0ABPADiHFE9VQojA8Ag4SqOm6hBYyKxcOBUHxhOJNRRh2OAJeQJB-MlT0FH3FqMeJ2xNzu4u5vxgLH2M3m8DA9SW2zm4v4DRqN3qNOhrSuqHgSPCtvtyJKqC5AG5cLhQJBYI7nTg9dJmlAyKzUiwfTBIjASNhsDAAAoYLRkECoerwDgwGQpGBiCAQGMwABu6EZ6Cd8H9geg7XACBosFTUN1sJl8IYepD3lQEBYABpdYPxwi-bgZGwwMBRWAYIJ+hwoBAAJIQADS8BpuJkJFxVwAVvBFxkach4FUABQgM8XqD9k-ny-X+CjmAXff96CMmAqQAJT9qu+Ybj++4wJSUE0rIMBvs+V43jAABkMAARWXY9EsMB3tMd6-jSMHLo+75QMBwEwDhPSEFGkhRDAbJMXkHCSBwd4AAZ7iRAAkUIAFIAMq4qCsRYUBSw0kR+7AQiMDeDei7wPUMBXGwsBgCAsBFvOamsjA5HPrEXHAX6PQIrgVkBsSukpOYUAAIxhggKAYAgsQcPA1JaHe4RQneAA6UQ2PJ4SpN+d6IN+YSYVAgEgTgVQ0bq4Hrluu77oed6Bm2UCxeZureVAxgtmA+XzMg2x+giRWzvOi5EsulK8Yex5Ph+N73sZi6vp1UAoV+cH-glMagXBMEQHBCFIV18DofFiWpT0JVlcRpFGQNtWNnZhYOZgABMrlINSnneb58D+YFIVhQiEVRTFMBxZJSXYCltEEHhBGtdlMi5a23gFc9VErXRBCJmSICYW4LTRkBcDQ2Q6AmqGUYLTI6CLnAZCKRtlJgEQsDViy9Tfiyv444xFYo4p7EpOO4MQ+ERkFmtXA0-FmDiFW6CoGwDZM1TIBMSxMBsRx3EZKdHkLcj02siTTKTQJIliRJY1STIMnIPJZkWYQVmrS0ZV5UDVU1dZ5lAA) for all the above